# Is there any disadvantage to using NTSC video system on a Canon EOS R6?

Tags: formats

A setting on the Canon EOS R6 allows you to choose between NTSC and PAL for the video system. I am somewhat aware that NTSC and PAL were analog video standards used by (roughly) North America and Europe respectively. However, I am not expecting to ever play back my videos on analog TVs, so it looks to me like the main distinction is that the NTSC option allows access to higher frame rate movie recording (59.94p vs 50p for PAL).

To me, the higher frame rate is better, and so I see no reason not to use NTSC, even though I live in a former-PAL region. Am I missing any disadvantage of doing this? Will it impact any still photography functionality?

Comment: Using NTSC won’t impact functionality, but if you live in an area powered by an AC 50 Hz electricity network (like most of Europe), be prepared to see flickering in your videos whenever you film subjects that are lit up with LED lights.

Answer (score 0):

I think the main consideration has to be - what frame rate are you planning to deliver your finished videos at, and will you be doing any frame rate conversion to get there?  If your delivery fps will be a multiple of 25, then 59.94 fps won't divide evenly, and any frame rate conversion would have to interpolate or drop frames at an uneven rate to compensate. If you're delivering a finished video at 30fps, or 60fps, then the NTSC rate may make more sense for your project.

The [specs for the camera](https://www.canon.co.uk/cameras/eos-r6/specifications/) also suggest the video modes target a data bitrate for a given frame rate:

eg 4K (59.94p/50.00p): IPB Approx. 230 Mbps

So I guess it's possible you might get slightly higher quality per frame if you're running at 50fps vs 59.94 fps. Whether you could see this in practice is unlikely I reckon.